# How to meta_query compare with a substr of the db value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to query some posts from a custom posttype in my site and Here's what I'm doing:

```
$query_adresses = array (
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'cat'       => $_GET["cat"],
        'post_type'=> 'adressen',
        'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'postcode',
                'value'   => $target_zips,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
      );
```

As you can see I'm checkin for matches in zipcodes. The `$target_zips` array contains a set of zipcode values like: `5641, 1011, 3455`. The `postcode` fields in my posts contain values like: `5641GH, 1011AB, 3455TR`. So what I need to do is make this comparison but only use the first 4 characters of the posts `postcode` field for it. Is this possible? And how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `REGEXP` search:

```
$query_adresses = array (
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'cat'       => $_GET["cat"],
    'post_type'=> 'adressen',
    'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'postcode',
            'value'   => '^(5641|1011|3455)',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        )
    )
);
```

#### Translation of the regular expression:

`^`: assert position at start of the string

`(5641|1011|3455)`: capturing group matches `5641` OR `1011` OR `3455`

More info [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments).

Comment: Works great! makes a whole lot of difference.